# Why did we use "de" and not "des" in the following sentence ?

Tags: articles, de

I have the following sentence:

> Maintenant il y a des immeubles modernes, avant il y avait **de** vieilles
>   maisons.

I was expecting *des* instead of *de* since what is after is plural.
I know it would be *de* if the sentence was negated, but it is not.

So what is the rule in this case ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the adjective precedes the noun, then we use **de** instead of **des**. In this case, *vieilles* which is the adjective is before the noun *maisons*. In the first sentence, there is **des**,because *modernes* which is the adjective is after the noun *immeubles*.